# Como mesclar sublistas de uma classe e retornar o resultado usando Linq e C#

Tags: c#, linq

Olá, estou trabalhando com c# e tenho a seguinte situação:

- Tenho 2 classes no sistema, `Order` e `ProductSold`;
- `Order` contém como propriedade um `List<ProductSold>`;
- Em determinada ViewModel, tenho que pegar uma lista dos `ProductSold` que estão dentro de uma `List<Order>`;

As classes estão da seguinte forma...

```
public class ProductSold 
{ 
    ... 
}
public class Order 
{
    public List<ProductSold> ProductSolds { get; set; }
}
public class ViewModel
{
    public void getProductSolds(List<Order> orders) 
    {
        return orders.Select(x => x.ProductSolds).toList(); // ???
    }
}
```

Fazendo dessa forma, eu acabo tendo uma lista de listas de `ProductSold`. Preciso mesclar essas listas e retornar somente uma. Como proceder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para retornar uma lista só, utilize o método SelectMany:

```
return orders.SelectMany(x => x.ProductSolds).ToList();
```

Exemplo no .NETFiddle feito pelo colega Rovann Linhalis: [Exemplo](http://dotnetfiddle.net/CYFmjD)

Comment: Coloquei no .NETFiddle um exemplo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/CYFmjD

Comment: Incluí na resposta seu exemplo, obrigado cara! Vou começar a postar as respostas com .NETFiddle também para aumentar a qualidade, valeu!

Comment: kra tem uns 3 minutos que achei aqui, mas muito obrigado, era isso mesmo que tava caçando xD